# iOS AVFoundation - 4K video

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

Ok so, got a camera app, have been able to set resolution previously and conditionally like so:

```
        if ([_captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080]) {
            _captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;
        } else if ([_captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720]) {
            _captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;
        } else {
            _captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
        }
```

Thanks to iPhone 6S, I know we can get 4K video. However, doesn't seem to be a preset for that resolution. Will the `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` else statement default to that, or is there a constant that I can set for that resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use AVCaptureSessionPreset3840x2160

It's the new 4K AVCaptureSessionPreset that doesn't yet appear to be documented online, but it'll show up in your autocomplete if you're running the latest Xcode beta.

Comment: See here for more info about AVFoundation changes on the 6s/6s+ https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21694

Comment: Had a feeling that would be the case. Thank you!